# Changing the Date object timezone

Tags: javascript, html, date, spoofing, spoof

Is it possible to change the timezone on the actual `Date` object. I don't mean to convert the timezone or anything like that, I mean when any successive calls to `new Date()` or other Date objects are made it will be spoofed by an offset and the String timzeone in `new Date` will show the spoofed timezone.

Comment: Date objects don't have a time zone, so impossible to "spoof". The offset and timezone used for *toString* comes from system settings.